# Detect the largest number in inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want Detect the largest number in inputs and done alert for it, How is it in following code by jQuery?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3cTqD/

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">

<button>Click Me</button>

$('button').live('click', function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        var val = $('this').val();
        alert(val); // i want done alert largest number from input
    })
})
```

Comment: It you even bother to try to come up with an own algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( 'button' ).live( 'click', function(){
    alert(
        Math.max.apply( Math, $( 'input' ).map( function(){
            return 0|this.value;
        }).get())
    );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').live('click', function(){
    var i = 0;
    $('input').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val > i) i = val;
    });
    alert(i);
});
```

Comment: Code looks correct. I replaced your code in jsfiddle given by Kate. why it is not working ?

Comment: This code does not work, if all entered numbers are lower than zero!

Comment: so change the `0` to `-Infinity`